# Count occurrences of value in a set of variables in R (per column)

Tags: r

I have this data and I want to figure out a way to know how many ones and how many zeros are in each column (ie Arts and Crafts). I have been trying different things but it hasn't been working. Does anyone have any suggestions?

[image: data]

Comment: Try `table(myData[, "myColumn"])`

Comment: If you want to count the number of occurrences row vice. You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015557/count-occurrences-of-value-in-a-set-of-variables-in-r-per-row

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `table()` function in R. This creates a categorical representation of your data. Additionally here convert list to vector I have used `unlist()` function.

```
df1 <- read.csv("Your_CSV_file_name_here.csv")
table(unlist(df1$ArtsAndCrafts))
```

If you want to row vice categorize the number of zeros and ones you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015557/count-occurrences-of-value-in-a-set-of-variables-in-r-per-row) question in Stackoverflow.