# How to count the number of occurrences of a given value for each row?

Tags: r, dataframe, recode

I'm sure this is a really easy fix but I can't seem to find the answer... I am trying to create a column at the end of my dataframe that is a sum of the number of times a specific value (say "1") appears across that row. So for example, if I started with the following dataframe:

```
X1 <- c(5,1,7,8,1,5)
X2 <- c(5,0,0,2,3,7)
X3 <- c(6,2,3,4,1,7)
X4 <- c(1,1,5,2,1,7)

df <- data.frame(id,X1,X2,X3,X4)

  id X1 X2 X3 X4
1  1  5  5  6  1
2  2  1  0  1  1
3  3  7  0  3  5
4  4  8  2  4  2
5  5  1  3  2  1
6  6  5  7  7  7
```

and I was trying to identify how many times the value "1" appears across that row, I would want the output to look like this:

```
  id X1 X2 X3 X4 one_appears
1  1  5  5  6  1           2
2  2  1  0  1  1           3
3  3  7  0  3  5           0
4  4  8  2  4  2           0
5  5  1  3  2  1           2
6  6  5  7  7  7           0
```

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count occurrences of value in a set of variables in R (per row)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015557/count-occurrences-of-value-in-a-set-of-variables-in-r-per-row)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` on a logical matrix

```
df$one_appears <- rowSums(df == 1, na.rm = TRUE)
```

-output

```
> df
  id X1 X2 X3 X4 one_appears
1  1  5  5  6  1           2
2  2  1  0  1  1           3
3  3  7  0  3  5           0
4  4  8  2  4  2           0
5  5  1  3  2  1           2
6  6  5  7  7  7           0
```

Answer (score 7):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    one = rowSums(across(everything(), ~ .x == 1))
  )

# A tibble: 6 × 6
     id    X1    X2    X3    X4   one
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     5     5     6     1     2
2     2     1     0     2     1     2
3     3     7     0     3     5     0
4     4     8     2     4     2     0
5     5     1     3     1     1     3
6     6     5     7     7     7     0
```

EDIT:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    one = rowSums(across(starts_with("X"), ~ .x == 1))
  )

df %>% 
  mutate(
    one = rowSums(across(X1:X4, ~ .x == 1))
  )
```

Comment: please add `library(dplyr)` to your excellent answer.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to exclude certain columns (e.g., id)? Say if I only wanted to do rowSums for [2:5]?

Comment: Nevermind sorry, I figured it out - thank you!

Comment: @user21027866 Yes, sorry for the late reply. I have added a few lines showing you how that could be done in different ways, perhaps the same as your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `apply` with `sum`:

```r
id <- c(1:6)
X1 <- c(5,1,7,8,1,5)
X2 <- c(5,0,0,2,3,7)
X3 <- c(6,2,3,4,1,7)
X4 <- c(1,1,5,2,1,7)

df <- data.frame(id,X1,X2,X3,X4)
df$one_appear = apply(df, 1, \(x) sum(x == 1))
df
#>   id X1 X2 X3 X4 one_appear
#> 1  1  5  5  6  1          2
#> 2  2  1  0  2  1          2
#> 3  3  7  0  3  5          0
#> 4  4  8  2  4  2          0
#> 5  5  1  3  1  1          3
#> 6  6  5  7  7  7          0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This answer may not be the best of the approach, but an alternative that I tried so thought to share

## code

```r
library(dplyr)

X1 <- c(5,1,7,8,1,5)
X2 <- c(5,0,0,2,3,7)
X3 <- c(6,2,3,4,1,7)
X4 <- c(1,1,5,2,1,7)

df <- data.frame(X1,X2,X3,X4) %>% rowwise %>% 
mutate(across(starts_with('X'), function(x) ifelse(x==1,1,NA), .names = 'Y_{col}'), 
                                         one_appears=sum(across(starts_with('Y')), na.rm = T)
                                         )
```